# Joomla Single Contact Form component not sending emails

Tags: joomla, smtp, gmail, joomla-extensions, contact-form

I have this component configured and my system mail configured

[image]

[image]

but there is never any indication that this module sends an email at all. I don't get anything on my sender email or on my server's email.

the "mass email" feature in the admin console works, as well as other plugins using the exact same settings. So I feel like this module is missing something

Comment: Firstly is it a component or a module? you say different things in different places. Secondly a screenshot isn't much help - we need a component/module name and a joomla version to try and replicate the problem. Or a url for where your hosting the site

Comment: its a `Contacts` component.  `Contacts >> Single Contact`, Joomla 1.7

Comment: @GeorgeWilson see above, and also I'll repeat again that Mass Email works as well as my third party modules work for sending emails to users. Why doesn't contact component work? I have the email set properly/the same in multiple places

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only situation I've seen this happen (i.e. where mail appears to be setup correctly as "Mass Mail" and other mail functions work) is when the Contact being used for the contact form doesn't actually have a valid email address set.

Once it was a typo in the email address the other was a completely blank email field.

Comment: that is not the problem here, I just went into Contacts component and pasted in the email for the contact form. from browsing the net I've seen others that have my problem, but I don't see the clear resolution. Joomla 1.7

Comment: Ok, the 1.7 is kind of vital information - apart from being no longer supported and having serious security issues it also had several odd issues... what do you have your contact forms options set to?

Comment: which option? the only relevant one I can imagine is `Session Check` which is set to "No"

Comment: Is that in your Contact Global settings or in the specific menu item? And you're not getting any errors in the webserver log when submitting the form?

Comment: @ccpl contact global, in the menu item it is set to `use global`

Comment: anything in the web servers error log? Given you seem to have the session turned to off in global (I don't think the bug was affected by the menu settings) with out some error messages to point us in the right direction I can't suggest anything. I'd don't even have a copy of 1.7 anywhere to look at the code.

Comment: could it have to do with the system email being the same as this contact email?

Answer (score 0):

[VERIFIED]  I solved this problem by creating a contact with NO LINKED USER. 
Meaning , from contacts, I just put in the email I want to receive at and didn't specify anything else. After Save I contined to the menu to specify a Single contact and picked the contact I've just created.